# How to modify MIB_IFTABLE

Tags: java, windows, virtualbox

My Oracle Java 1.8.0_71 `SecureRandom` was exceedingly slow; in debugging I discovered that SecureRandom was blocking because it was trying to gather system entropy (`sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator#getSystemEntropy()`) by hashing the names of network interfaces, among other things. It makes a Java call to `NetworkInterface.getAll` which on Windows calls `GetIfTable` which reads from the `MIB_IFTABLE`.

The cause of the slowness is that I have 903 NICs, most of them artifacts of clean uninstalls of VirtualBox. I have followed multiple threads (like [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=28172)) to attempt to remove the spurious NICs (e.g. net859, net860, etc.). I cannot find any reference to these in the registry or on my file system.

How does the MIB_IFTABLE get generated and how can I modify it to remove the spurious NICs?

Comment: Links to [NetworkInterface.getAll](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~michaelm/7084560/webrev.1/raw_files/new/src/windows/native/java/net/NetworkInterface.c​), [GetIfTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379157(v=vs.85).aspx​), and [MIB_IFTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366842(v=vs.85).aspx​​).